# Start MongoDB in cmd on windows 10

Tags: mongodb

I Want to install MongoDB and start it,I used this codes in cmd 
`mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath C:\mongodb\data\db --logpath C:\mongodb\log\mongo,log --logappend --rest --install`
And For start this used this code in cmd `net start MongoDB` But I give this Error
`The service name is invalid.
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2185.`
How I Can fixed it?I'm searching any more time But don't find any Solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, the `MongoDB` service isn't installed, because you executed the install command without admin privilegues.

To solve this, open the start menu, enter `powershell`, right-click and select *run as administrator*. Now you should be able to run the install command.

```
mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath C:\mongodb\data\db --logpath C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log --logappend --rest --install
```

If you encounter the error again, after you tried to install the service as an admin user, you should have a look at the log file (in your case *C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log*)

Btw. there was an typo in your command for the logfile name (command instead of point for the filename)